# gstreamer tutorial 1 playbin error on windows

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I’m having a problem with gstreamer tutorial 1.  It is failing to open a pipeline.  I am running Windows 10 on a Surface Book, using Visual Studio 2019 Community.
I installed the following:
gstreamer-1.0-devel-msvc-x86_64-1.16.2.msi
gstreamer-1.0-msvc-x86_64-1.16.2.msi
I downloaded the tutorials.  I copied all of the dlls from C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin to the Debug directory where the example builds are copied.  I am able to build 16 of the 19 tutorials.  The 3 remaining tutorials are missing references.  When I run tutorial 1, it has a problem with playbin.  I added an error type to the call to get the error info.  The source code is as follows:

```
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GstElement *pipeline;
  GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;
  GError* error = NULL;

  /* Initialize GStreamer */    
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  /* Build the pipeline */
  pipeline =
  gst_parse_launch
  ("playbin uri=https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm",
   &error);
```

Using a breakpoint, the error code is 1 and the message is "no element \"playbin\""
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFjLt.png)

When I use the following at the command line, the video streams fine:
    C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin>gst-launch-1.0 -v playbin 
    uri=https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm
    WARNING: no real random source present!
    Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
    Pipeline is PREROLLING ...

After that, the video plays fine.  Any idea why I’m having a problem with playbin when used in code, but not at the command line with gst-launch?  It feels like I’m still missing a link to a dll or something.
Thanks,
Mark